# WebGL: Is there an efficient way to upload only part of an image/canvas as a texture?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, webgl

I am working on a 2D layer-based application, and I'd like to do the compositing using WebGL. The layers might be shifted relative to each other, and each frame only a small (rectangular) part of each layer may change. However, the width and height of that rectangular part may vary unpredictably.
I would like to use one canvas (2D) and one texture per layer, and each frame redraw on each canvas only the part of the layer that has been modified, then simply upload that small area to the GPU to update the corresponding part to texture, before the GPU makes the compositing for me. However I have not found an efficient way to upload just a part of an image to a part of a texture. It seems that `texSubImage2D()` *can* update a part of a texture, but only takes full images/canvases, and it does not seem to be possible to specify a rectangular area of the image to use.

I have thought of a few ways of doing this, but each seems to have obvious overhead:

- use `getImageData()` + `texSubImage2D()` to only upload to the GPU the part that changes (overhead in converting the canvas pixel data to ImageData)
- re-upload the whole layer canvas each frame with `texImage2D()`
- or create/resize a small canvas2D to the correct dimension to fit perfectly for each layer modification, then use `texSubImage2D()` to send it to update the related texture (memory reservation overhead)

So, is there a way to specify a part of an image/a canvas for the texture ? Something like `texImagePart2D()` and `texSubImagePart2D`, which would both accept four more parameters, `sourceX`, `sourceY`, `sourceWidth` and `sourceHeight` to specify the rect area of the image/canvas to use ?

Comment: In most of the embedded GPUs atleast, the TexSubImage2D API will be slower. It might be better to use TexImage2D itself.

Comment: So there is no faster way than to re-upload the whole texture, even if only a part of it was modified ? But I don't understand, why would it be slower, if it only uploads a small rect and not the whole texture ? Is it because modifying an existing texture is slow ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately no there is no way to upload a portion of a canvas/image.

OpenGL ES 2.0 on which WebGL is based does not provide a way to do that. OpenGL ES 3.0 does provide a way to upload smaller rectangle of the source to a texture or portion of a texture so maybe the next version of WebGL will provide that feature.

For now you could have a separate canvas to help upload. First size the canvas to the match the portion you want to upload

```
canvasForCopying.width = widthToCopy;
canvasForCopying.height= heightToCopy;
```

Then copy the portion of the canvas you wanted to copy to the canvas for copying

```
canvasForCopying2DContext.drawImage(
    srcCanvas, srcX, srcY, widthToCopy, heightToCopy,
    0, 0, widthToCopy, heightToCopy);
```

Then use that to upload to the texture where you want it.

```
gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, destX, destY, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                 canvasForCopying);
```

`getImageData` will likely be slower because the browser has to call `readPixels` to *get* the image data and that stalls the graphics pipeline. The browser does not have to do that for `drawImage`.

As for why `texImage2D` can sometimes be faster than `texSubImage2D` it depends on the driver/GPU but apparently sometimes `texImage2D` can be implemented using DMA whereas `texSubImage2D` can not. `texImage2D` can also be pipelined by making a new texture and lazily discarding the old one where as `texSubImage2D` can't.

Personally I wouldn't worry about it but if you want to check, time uploading tens of thousands of textures using both `texImage2D` and `texSubImage2D` (don't time just one as graphics are pipelined). You'll probably find `texSubImage2D` is faster if your texture is large and the portion you want to update is smaller than 25% of the texture. At least that's what I found last time I checked. Most current drivers are at least optimized in that if you call `texSubImage2D` and happen to be replacing the entire contents they'll call the `texImage2D` code internally.

## update

There's a couple of things you can do

1. For images you can use `fetch` and `ImageBitmap` to load a portion of an image into an `ImageBitamp` which you can then upload that. Example of getting a portion of an image

   In the example below we call `fetch`, then get a `Blob` and use that blob to make an `ImageBitmap` with only a portion of the image. The result can be passed to `texImage2D` but in the interest of brevity the sample just uses it in a 2d canvas.

```js
fetch('https://i.imgur.com/TSiyiJv.jpg', {mode: 'cors'})
.then((response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw response;
  }
  return response.blob();
})
.then((blob) => {
  const x = 451;
  const y = 453;
  const width = 147;
  const height = 156;
  return createImageBitmap(blob, x, y, width, height);
}).then((bitmap) => {
  useit(bitmap);
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});

// -- just to show we got a portion of the image

function useit(bitmap) {
  const ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);
  ctx.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
}
```

2. In WebGL2 there are the `gl.pixelStorei` settings

   UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH     // how many pixels a row of the source is
     UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS      // how many rows to skip from the start of the source
     UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS    // how many pixels to skip from the left of the source

   so using those 3 settings you can tell webgl2 the source is wider but the portion you want from it is smaller. You pass a smaller width to `texImage2D` and the 3 settings above help tell WebGL how to get out the smaller portion and where to start.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I think I'll use that drawImage / texSubImage2D workaround. Regards.